# How can I solve the SonarCloud issues in routes/users.js file of my backend project?

Tags: javascript, issue-tracking, sonarcloud

I'm working on this backend and SonarCloud keep telling me that there's 2 issues in the file routes/users.js that I don't know how to remove, could you please help me ?

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZyEi.png)]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPLq0.png)

I tried ChatGPT but it didn't work and SonarCloud told me to use only plain string values and it doesn't help much.

I tried ChatGPT who told me to use a "sanitize" function but it didn't work and SonarCloud told me to use only plain string values and it doesn't help much.